# On using an article at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, definite-article

I have this sentence:

> Section 2 anticipates the findings of this section.

Shall I add an article (`The`) before `Section 2` which starts the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not use an article. Two is a cardinal number and cardinal numbers behave like determiners and do not require an article.

When you put a noun in front of a cardinal number (section, part, number, apartment...) you make a kind of 'compound cardinal number', and cardinal numbers don't require an article.

Note that ordinal numbers (first, second, third, etc) are more like adjectives, so ordinals go in front of the noun and they do require an article, so you would have to write "The second section...".